# Scala generic wildcard and specific type

Tags: scala, scala-generics

I have the `mappings` value:

```
val mappings: Map[Class[_] ,Iterable[AttributeKeyAndValue] => AnyRef]
```

is it possible to make it more typesafe like

```
val mappings: Map[Class[T], Iterable[AttributeKeyAndValue] => T]
```

where `T` plays the same role as underscore. I'd expect compiler to complain, if it meets this code:

```
val mappings: Map[Class[T], Iterable[AttributeKeyAndValue] => T] = Map(
  classOf[String], attrs => 1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't parametrize `val`s so no, not like that.

Looking at your request, it doesn't make much sense. Lets say that this: `val mappings: Map[Class[T], Iterable[AttributeKeyAndValue] => T]` was valid and the compiler would complain.

You would either parametrize all the entries in the map with the same type, ie. `T` or have each entry with it's own parametrized type making it impossible to know which type it is when retrieving the entries with the `apply` or `get` methods.

I suggest you stick with the `Class[_]` because the only way to parametrize this is to force all the entries to have the same type. For example if you were able to parametrize it in `Map[Class[String], ...]` then you would only be able to put 1 entry in the map, the one where the key is `classOf[String]`

Answer (score 2):

Wildcards in Scala are just a specific simple case of existential types, and what you want would be a more complex one because you want to use the same `T` in two places. Something like `Seq[(Class[T], AttributeKeyAndValue => T) forSome { type T }]`. But note where you need to put `forSome`: there is no equivalent place if you want `Map`! E.g. `Map[Class[T], AttributeKeyAndValue => T] forSome { type T }` would mean there is a single `T` for the entire map.

What I'd suggest is creating a type which presents a more type-safe interface, even if you need casts inside:

```
class Mappings private (contents: Map[Class[_], Iterable[AttributeKeyAndValue] => AnyRef]) {
  def get[T](clazz: Class[T]) = contents.get(clazz).asInstanceOf[Option[Iterable[AttributeKeyAndValue] => T]]

  def +[T](clazz: Class[T], value: Iterable[AttributeKeyAndValue] => T) = new Mappings(contents + (clazz, value))

  // any other methods you want
}

object Mappings {
  val empty = new Mappings(Map.empty)
}

// elsewhere
Mappings.empty + (classOf[String], attrs => "a") // type-checks
Mappings.empty + (classOf[String], attrs => 1) // doesn't type-check
```

You can actually improve the API to avoid manually passing classes, so you just write `get[String]` and `+(attrs => 1)` automatically infers it needs  `classOf[Int]`, but I decided to show the simple idea here.

Comment: Yes, `mappings` actually a private val in such kind of wrapper.

Comment: In that case, I'd just work with `Map[Class[_], Iterable[AttributeKeyAndValue] => AnyRef]` inside the wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

Well, compiler does not know what is `T` in example you've provided. 
So, as an option you can defined `mappings` function parametrised by `T`:

```
       def mappings[T](x: AttributeKeyAndValue => T): 
             Map[Class[T], AttributeKeyAndValue => T] = Map(classOf[T] -> x)
```

usage:

```
  val mappping = mappings(x => x.toString)
```

and the type that compiler will be able to infer is:

```
  mappping : Map[Class[String], AttributeKeyAndValue => String]
```

Comment: This will make for a map that can only have 1 key.

Comment: Well, you've got the idea. If you have list of values that you need to populate you can pass a seq as parameter:  `def mappings[T](xs: List[AttributeKeyAndValue => T]): Map[Class[T], AttributeKeyAndValue => T] = xs.map(x => classOf[T] -> x).toMap`

Comment: Again, the returned map will have all it's keys parametrize in the same type. Which would be fine under normal cases, but here, if you put a `classOf[String]` as a key in the map you cannot put another key as `classOf[Int]`. This is just unnatural behavior

Comment: Well true, but if author has specific case where `T` can be subclasses of class `Animal` for example it will work fine for him.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it around into a case class?

```
  type Attrs = Iterable[AttributeKeyAndValue]

  case class Mappings[T](m: Map[Class[T], Attrs => T]

  object Mappings {
    implicit def mk[T](m: Map[Class[T], Attrs => T): Mappings[T] = Mappings(m)
  } 

  val mappings: Mappings[_] = Map(classOf[String] -> { (_:Attrs) => "foo" })  // Works

  val badMappings: Mappings[_] =  Map(classOf[String] -> { (_:Attrs) => 1 })  // Fails
```